# How to change the visibility when the click is outside of the control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a User control in WPF that is built on MVVM format. The usercontrol is a collection of viewmodels arranged in a panel. The number of pannels (or related views/ view models) will be decided at run time.

Each panel is a user control and refers a view model (case as workspaces). Each pannel consists of a button and a listbox. Initially when loaded only the buttons of all the pannels will be shown. On click of button the corresponding List box would be shown. Till this it is working fine.

What i need is if the user clicks on any other area the curent open listbox should collapse. If user selects another button, that listbox should be shown and this current open list box should be collapsed.

Currently it shows on button click but never closes

For showing the list box i am using the below code in the button trigger :

```
<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference ListBoxDrop}" 
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}">
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
```

Any suggestion ?

- Girija

Answer (score 1):

just add another trigger!

```
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button" Width="75" >
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference ListBoxDrop}"  
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference ListBoxDrop}"  
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This works in case only if i click another button. If i click on an empty area then the listbox doesnot go

Answer (score 0):

Fred's answer might just be it.

However the expected behavior for the user is for the listbox to get focus on button click.

So the the button will lose focus even when the corresponding listbox (or its item) is selected by the user. Thus hiding the listbox again.

I would suggest to modify it like this:

```
<ListBox.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus"> 
     <EventTrigger.Actions>
       <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myListBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1"/>
         </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger.Actions> 
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus"> 
     <EventTrigger.Actions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myListBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</ListBox.Triggers>
```

And for the corresponding button, set an event handler in codebehind...

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myListBox.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set the visibilty in event triggers . I am new to WPF so not able to figure out.

Comment: The lisbox is not actually a list box , it is a Grid that contains the listbox along with a search box. Sorry for not telling earlier.

Comment: Somethings are best done in codebehind. There are XAML only solutions to focus an element, but its not worth it, if it's simply a line of code in c#. It doesnt matter if the target is a grid. Just set the name of the grid as myGrid or something & update the targetname attribute above

Comment: The listbox doesnot go if i click on anywhere aoutside. I tried teh code behind and the XAML you suggested, but it doesnot work.